# Who is the character sporting a mohican whom Onizuka is parodying?

Tags: great-teacher-onizuka

I tried Google searches for a list of parodies that appear in G.T.O without any luck. I'm also not even sure if this is a parody, other than the fact that it would be super random if it wasn't.

Who is the Mohican character that Onizuka is parodying in the picture? *(Appearing in episode 17)*

[image: Mohican Character Parody from G.T.O ep17]

Comment: Mohawk? I don't know I've ever heard it called a "mohican".

Comment: @Catija Mohican may be a term found only in England...just guessing though.

Comment: Yeah, the Brits call it a "Mohican", and, interestingly enough, so do the Japanese (モヒカン _mohikan_).

Comment: first of all, in german, it is `Irokese` (*ee-row-kehseh*). then, are you sure, it is some kind of parody? couldn't it be the stereotypical rowdy?

Answer (score -1):

This type of hairstyle and dress usually references the unnamed punks that get killed in Hokuto no Ken (1984).

Comment: Would you happen to have any sources to back up your answer? It’s quite bare right now…

Comment: Do you want a bunch of screenshots of other anime using this getup to parody Hokuto no Ken or what are you looking for?

Comment: *How* do you know that it’s a parody specifically of Hokuto no Ken? That’s the main claim that would benefit from backing up with sources.

Comment: Because of the hairstyle and dress, like I wrote. It's a pretty common reference in anime, but it might also be a reference to some live-action show. There's not enough context. I watched the short segment again to see if there was more to it, but there wasn't.

Comment: Is there something that ties Onizuka's mannerisms to Fist of the North Star in particular? (e.g. a Kenshiro quote, an iconic pose, a name drop, etc.) Because otherwise Onizuka just looks like a punk which exist outside the scope of anime and Japan as a whole originating in the UK in the 1970s. Punks do have quite a presence in FotNS but it didn't invent the apunkalypse as the trope is called, instead it essentially cribs it from Mad Max (1979) which FotNS's mangaka cites as one of his 2 main inspirations.

Comment: No, nothing of the sort, which is why I wrote that this usually references Hokuto no Ken in anime. But there's nothing in the scene that would be usable as proof. But since it's an anime and has other references to  anime, like Doraemon, it's more likely for this to reference Hokuto no Ken than some non-Japanese phenomenon. Though, it might also reference some Japanese live-action show from around that time.